# Googlecast labels not localized to device's language

Tags: ios, localization, google-cast

According to Googlecast's release notes and this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132135605#comment1), localization should already be supported/implemented by default when using the new 4.4.2 SDK. Checking the actual `GoogleCastUIResources.bundle` also confirms the new translations. However for my iOS applications, changing the device language to any other languages still gives me the strings in English.

Am I missing any intermediate steps to get localization for my iOS apps?

Answer (score 0):

Add the language in your project file, that worked for me.

[image]